# Zipped folder from NodeJS express server returned using res.download results as invalid file when downloading in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a node js express server endpoint that zipped a folder which has pdf files on it, and being returned using res.download(zippedFolder)

Note: For instance the endpoint for downloading the zipped folder is /generateZippedFile ,
When I try to use that endpoint, I can successfully download the zipped folder.
The problem is when I integrate it in FE, there's an error saying the the zipped file is
invalid.

In front end using React I tried this way.

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'
const res = await generatePDFZipFile(ids)
saveAs(new Blob([res.data], {type:'application/zip'}), 'zippedFile')
```

Note : I have tried type:octet/stream, and many more. But still fails

It successfully downloaded the folder but it says invalid file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.